# Releasing BufferedReader.readLine() while locked with synchronized method

Tags: java, bufferedreader, synchronized

currently i have a code like the following one:

```
public class CtrlServer {
    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Map<Integer, Socket> s;
    private Map<Integer, PrintWriter> out;
    private Map<Integer, BufferedReader> in;

    public CtrlServer(){
        ss = null;
        s = new HashMap<Integer, Socket>();
        out = new HashMap<Integer, PrintWriter>();
        in = new HashMap<Integer, BufferedReader>();
    }
    public CtrlServer(int port) throws Exception{
        this();
        if(!initialize(port))
            throw new Exception();
    }
    public synchronized boolean initialize(int port){
        try{close();}catch(Exception e){}
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean getClient(int id, int timeout){
        close(id);
        try{
            ss.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            s.put(id, socket);
            in.put(id, new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())));
            out.put(id, new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true));
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }finally{
            try{ss.setSoTimeout(0);}catch(SocketException e){}
        }
    }
    public synchronized String getResponse(int id, String command){
        try{
            send(id, command);
            String response =  in.get(id).readLine();
            return response;
        }catch(Exception e){
            close(id);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public synchronized void send(int id, String message){
        try{
            out.get(id).println(message);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void broadcast(String message){
        for(Entry<Integer, PrintWriter> writer: out.entrySet())
            send(writer.getKey(), message);
    }
    public synchronized boolean isAlive(int id){
        try{
            if(getResponse(id, "alive").equals("OK"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }catch(Exception e){
            close(id);
            return false;
        }
    }
    public synchronized void close(int id){
        try{in.remove(id);}catch(Exception e){}
        try{out.remove(id);}catch(Exception e){}
        try{s.remove(id).close();}catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void close(){
        try{ss.close();}catch (Exception e){}
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Socket> client : s.entrySet()){
            close(client.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

problem comes when want to call the close() method and there is already another thread on getResponse() on the ReadLine() part

is there any way to force either the getResponse or the bufferedReader.ReadLine() to throw a exception or some way to make it stop, release the resource or something?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Handler instance which holds your socket, input, output and runs a reading thread for each handler.

This will replace and simplify most of the shared code here.